# Insert Data in distan MongoDB on Azure

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure

I try to insert multiple data in MongoDB located on Linux, on Azure VM using C#, and this is the code with no error, I try to connect to the URI than insert, but it look nothing happen

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String uri = "mongodb://user:pass@hostsite:port/dbName";
        var client = new MongoClient(uri);
        var MongoDB = client.GetDatabase("dbName");
        var Collec = MongoDB.GetCollection<BOSBourse>("tabelname");
        var document = new BOSBourse
        {
            Name = "aaa",
            Price = "11.5"
        };
        var document2 = new BOSBourse
        {
            Name = "bbb",
            Price = "9.20"
        };

        Collec.InsertManyAsync(new[] { document, document2 });

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    class BOSBourse
    {
        public ObjectId ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Update (Solution)
Just don't use Username and Password for the URI:**

```
string uri = "mongodb://hostSite:27017/DBName";
```

Comment: You should open mongodb port on Azure.

Comment: yes it  is already open, I comment the bindIP for local host, I see this link https://github.com/sedouard/mongodb-mva/tree/master/module5_running_in_cloud

Comment: Can you connect to that server from mongo shell?

Comment: I use shh, but I will see with shell